# Understanding avoiding Dead-code eliminations consequnces

Tags: java, jmh, dead-code

I'm reading JMH samples and now I'm at the section about [***safe-looping***](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/code-tools/jmh/file/bb860b8d1eb6/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_34_SafeLooping.java). Here is an example:

```
@Benchmark
public void measureRight_2() {
    for (int x : xs) {
        sink(work(x));
    }
}

@CompilerControl(CompilerControl.Mode.DONT_INLINE)
public static void sink(int v) {
    // IT IS VERY IMPORTANT TO MATCH THE SIGNATURE TO AVOID AUTOBOXING.
    // The method intentionally does nothing.
}
```

But they made one caveat about this technique (emphasize mine).

> Sometimes, the cost of sinking the value into a Blackhole is
>   dominating the nano-benchmark score. In these cases, one may try to do
>   a make-shift "sinker" with non-inlineable method. **This trick is *very***
>   **VM-specific, and can only be used if you are verifying the generated**
>   **code** (that's a good strategy when dealing with nano-benchmarks
>   anyway).

I do not quite understand what actuall a VM specific here. We use a method which is not supposed to be inlined. So the computation cannot be optimized away. What detail did I miss?

Comment: _Everything_ about black holes is JVM-specific. Some JVM can mark the method as "side effect-free" and eliminate calls to it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no guarantee that:

1. The no-inlining hint is communicated to JVM correctly;
2. The no-inlining hint is not deliberately ignored by JVM;
3. The no-inlining hint is not accidentally ignored by JVM;
4. The no-inlining hint is working, but JVM employs a cross-method optimization that avoids preparing arguments for known empty methods;
5. The no-inlining hint is working, but JVM employs some other magic optimization you cannot come up with in 15 minutes of thinking;

This may change from JVM family to JVM family, or even within the minor/patch releases of a given JVM family. This is why it is said to be very VM-specific, and to be used only if you actually control what happens exactly.